# Best way to setup Firebase in phonegap build

Tags: firebase, push-notification, phonegap-build

I have phonegap application on IOs and android build with **phonegap build** service. I want to add **push** notification and if possible use the other benefits of **Firebase** like Sync my database and Hosting,  push config or deep links.

I found a [project](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-fcm) for cordova and FCM but I guess I cant run it directly on build since many people had problems which are not solved yet. Also it only include Push service.

what is your suggestion to implement **Firebase** into my app to get most of the features? 
Thnx
Saeid